# .net Core register all services from given assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, grpc

What should I do to map all services dynamically in my grpc servicehost registration, instead of just mapping them one by one and editing this piece of code every time I add a new service?

I've managed to get all types in assembly that are in GrpcServices and has my custom attribute using this code:

```
public IEnumerable<Type> FindServiceInterfaces()
{
    string definedIn = typeof(GrpcServiceAttribute).Assembly.GetName().Name;
    Assembly assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetName().Name.Equals("GrpcServices"));
    foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
        if (type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(GrpcServiceAttribute), true).Length > 0)
            yield return type;
}
```

But I don't know how to cast/instantiate those above types and use them as follow but in generic/dynamic way:

```
var serverHostBuilder = new HostBuilder()
     .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
     {
          services.AddGrpcServer<ISimpleActionService, SimpleActionService>(new GrpcServerOptions { Url = "127.0.0.1", Port = 5000 });
     });
```

```
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddGrpcServer<TServiceInterface, TServiceImplementation>(
        this IServiceCollection serviceCollection,
        GrpcServerOptions options,
        ISerializer serializer
    )
        where TServiceInterface : class, IGrpcService
        where TServiceImplementation : class, IGrpcService, TServiceInterface
    {
        serviceCollection.AddScoped<TServiceInterface, TServiceImplementation>();
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<GrpcHost<TServiceInterface>>(
            appServices => GrpcHostFactory.Create<TServiceInterface>(appServices, options, serializer)
        );

        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IHostedService, GrpcBackgroundService<TServiceInterface>>();
        return serviceCollection;
    }
}
```

Desired solution: Just iterate through all of the interfaces that has my given attribute, find class that implements this interface IFoo -> Foo and add this -> `services.AddGrpcServer<IFoo,Foo>(.....)`

The only solution I found to instantiate those object is casting to already known type like this:

```
var desiredClass = (DesiredClassType)Activator.CreateInstance(assemblyType)
```

which is clearly not a solution for me.

**EDIT:**

I found out a nuget like Scrutor and it is almost a solution for me coded like this (btw thats a solution for a client which need only an interface instead of interface and its implementation class)

```
var clientServices = new ServiceCollection()
                        .Scan(scan => scan
                        .FromAssembliesOf(grpcServiceInterfaces)
                        .AddClasses(cl => cl.AssignableToAny(grpcServiceInterfaces))
                        .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                        .WithSingletonLifetime())
                        //.AddGrpcClient<ISimpleActionService> (clientOptions)
                        .BuildServiceProvider();
```

but I still don't know how to execute my custom AddSingletonMethod which execute Create method from **GrpcHostFactory**.

Answer (score 0):

My reflection-fu is somewhat weak these days, but you are 80% there already I would say. What you can do once you find the types of interest is to invoke the method of interest through reflection.

`services.AddGrpcServer<ISimpleActionService, SimpleActionService>(new GrpcServerOptions { Url = "127.0.0.1", Port = 5000 });`

becomes something like

`var methodInfo = services.GetType().GetMethod("AddGrpcServer").MakeGenericMethod(new []{ yourInterfaceType, yourImplType }).Invoke(new GrpcServerOptions { Url = "127.0.0.1", Port = 5000 });`

You cannot substitute types in generics at runtime without resorting to `MakeGenericType`/`MakeGenericMethod` etc from reflection.